# How do I create csv file from "SQL get rows" connector in Azure logic apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have created **recurrence** then I have connected **sql server** and getting rows from table . I want to **export csv file** from sql rows and **send email**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: what kinds of questions can I ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Remember to also to include Minimal, complete, verifiable examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Then, click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Compose CSV Action to convert the output of SQL to CSV.
2. Convert the output to Base64 string using the @base64() wdl function
3. Convert the base64 string to binary using the @base64toBinary() wdl function
4. Pass the output of Step 3 the to Attachment Content in logic app action
5. Give a name to the attachment with .csv extenstion

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type) for more details

Comment: There is no action named 'Compose CSV' anymore